# unity : How to control the tile value of a material when extract material from imported game object (fbx, blend etc)

Tags: unity

I import .blend (or .fbx) file into unity and i extract the materials. Sometimes the rusult of the material tiling is 5x5  , sometime 1x1. What makes unity decide what tiling value to be used when extracting material ? Can we control it ? i'm confused because normally it's 1x1 but at some case the material has tiling of 5x5.

Comment: Can you show us what you see in your 3D editing software, and what you see in Unity, so we understand the cases you're dealing with?

Comment: i'll post the images tomorrow. Basically, the texture in unity become 5x smaller then in my 3d app (blender). After extracting materials , the tiling is set to 5x5 automatically. But some other object/material has tiling of 1x1. I don't think Blender send internal data to control this tiling. Normally it should be 1x1.

Comment: If you can walk us through the steps to create a model that demonstrates this problem, we can use that to isolate the cause and test potential solutions or workarounds.